# Using pictures in class file

Tags: graphics, includegraphics, documentclass-writing, documentclass

I'm wondering how i can use a logo in a .cls file.
This logo shall be on all pages of the document.

The classfile looks like this:

```latex
\ProvidesClass{myclass}[2022/10/27 v1.12 MyClass]

\LoadClass{scrletter}
\RequirePackage{graphicx}
\includegraphics[scale=.15]{logo.png}
```

This throws the Error
`Missing \begin{document}`

How do i use the picture inside the `.cls` file correctly?
Note: Using the `\includegraphics...` command in the .tex file is not an option, i want the styling set up with just using the `\documentclass{myclass}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use (or not use) `\includgraphics` exactly where you can use a letter such as `X`. You would get the same error if you used `X` at that point in the class.

You can add the logo to the page head, either directly or using `fancyhdr` package

eg at its most basic

```
\def\@oddhead{\hfill\includegraphics{logo}}
```

Comment: exactly the syntax i was looking for